# route one subnet two nic

Tags: linux

[image]

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#Net1 ens192
auto ens192
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet static
address 1.1.1.2/29

#Vlan511
auto ens192.511
allow-hotplug ens192.511
iface ens192.511 inet static
address 192.168.10.1/23
vlan_raw_device ens192

#Net2 ens224
auto ens224
allow-hotplug ens224
iface ens224 inet static
address 1.1.1.3/29

#Vlan513
auto ens224.513
allow-hotplug ens224.513
iface ens224.513 inet static
address 192.168.30.1/23
vlan_raw_device ens224

up route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 1.1.1.1
```

##########################################################

/etc/iptables/rules.v4

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/23 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.2
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.30.0/23 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.3
```

With this configuration, traffic from the ens224 interface goes through the ens192 interface. At the same time, their external IPs are different. The gateway is a common one for two networks.

How can I set up traffic from networks to go separately from each other? So that ens192.511 exits through ens192, and traffic from the ens224.513 network exits through ens224.

Comment: If you were using a single NIC this would be simpler. Any reason for having two NICs in the same LAN?